# Getting the page count from the LibreOffice Java SDK

Tags: java, libreoffice, uno

I'm developing an Java application which prints files selected by the user. The `LibreOffice` SDK/Uno seems perfect for this, since it allows me to print many different file types without relying on eternal GUIs (which is a must).

However, for this framework to fully meet my needs, it also needs to provide the page count before printing the document(s). I have spent a fair amount of time researching the answer, but the examples and the API which `OOo` and `LibreOffice` provide aren't the best.

Could anyone tell me definitively whether or not this interface will provide a page count or, alternatively, suggest an replacement? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this has been dormant for a while.  In case you still need an answer - yes you can get the page count from Libre Office via Java.

```
    int nPageCount = com.sun.star.uno.AnyConverter.toInt(
            xPropertySet.getPropertyValue("PageCount"));
```

So you'll need to use the API to load the document, interrogate the page count.  If you search for "uno" and "PageCount" you'll find complete code examples (such as [OO mail archives](http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=56507) which also apply to LibreOffice)

Comment: Thanks for the late answer! This project ended up dying, but I appreciate the response!